# Why click circle image , div not toggle using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why click circle image , div not toggle using javascript ?

When i click gray square, it's will toggle ok.

But Why toggle not work, when click circle image. How can i do for work.

```
<img src="http://images.wikia.com/gtawiki/images/archive/3/3e/20090730000919!PS3_Circle.png" style=" border: none;" id="image_test" onclick="showDivtest('div1')" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a3MKG/40/

```
<script>
function showDiv(id) {    
  $("#div1").toggle();
}    

$(document).click(function(e) { 
   if( !$('#image_test').is( e.target ) )
      $("#div1").hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: i cant find `showDivtest` function with in your code , help me to find it

Comment: For starters your HTML is invalid. You cannot have duplicate `ID=` values in HTML as jQuery/Javascript can only see the first.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems. Duplicate IDs are invalid HTML (I removed it from the IMG). You should also avoid mixing inline click handlers with jQuery event handlers (just use jQuery handlers for everything). Also you need to stop the original open click from propagating to the `document` as that immediately closed it again.

Here is a cleaned up simplified version:

**JSiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/a3MKG/54/

```
$('#image_test').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#div1").toggle();
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("#div1").length == 0) {
        $("#div1").hide();
    }
});
```

I use `closest` to determine of the clicked element is the displayed options, or a descendant of the options (so clicking on a LI or the UL will do the same job).